# Dynamic price into

Tags: price, dynamic-price

I must to modify the price of products. I extract the price from another database.
where is saved the price ? the name of variable is $price? what file?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is not that easy.
The price is saved in the `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table and is retrieved when the product is loaded.
But there is a catch (actually more than one).
The price you see displayed is calculated based on the discount rules that you have applied, based on the existence of a special price.
The prices are indexed in a table and read from that.

Comment: For to insert dinamicaly price i modified the class getFinalPrice(price.php) and i take the price from another db